# Bootstrap Carousel Is Not Pausing on hover Either with JS or Data Attribute Ways

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://www.bootply.com/EZIHvvW8FL) and let me know why the `pause` option is not working when the mouse pointer enters the carousel in both `js`  method as:

```
$(function(){
     $("#carousel-example-generic").carousel({
          pause: "hover"
     });
});
```

or `data-pause` attribute way as

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your bootply file it's working fine? Have you included the jquery file?

altough you can try it like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel({
      pause: "hover"
    });
});
```

I hope it helpes you out.

Comment: Thanks for reply adeels but this is still happeining for me on Chrome! it is pausing on Firefox but not on chrome!